# Proving that exists equivalence relation $r$ in set $A$ such that $ |A \setminus r| = n$

Tags: order-theory, cardinals, equivalence-relations

I am trying to show that if $|A| = m$ and $0\neq n \le m $ then exists equivalence relation $r$ in set $A$ such that $ |A \setminus r| = n$. Could someone help me deal with it?

Comment: Can't you just arbitrarily glue points together?

Comment: I don't understand, could you explain it?

Comment: Draw your $m$ points on a sheet of paper. Now draw lines between the points until there are exactly $n$ connected components. This defines an equivalence relation.

Comment: Is it reflexive?

Comment: If you define it to be. :-)

Comment: Could you show me how to make this more formal?

Comment: Added some details as an answer.

Comment: By $A\setminus r$ do you mean $A/r$ ($A$ divided by $r$)?

Comment: I mean it is complement.

Answer (score 5):

Without loss of generality let $A = \{1, \ldots, m\}$. Choose $A_1 = \{1\}$, $A_2 = \{2\}$, ..., $A_{n-1} = \{n-1\}$, $A_n = \{n, \ldots, m\}$. This defines a partition of $A$ and hence and equivalence relation.

Comment: Correct, so +1. But I prefer your "draw a picture" comment. It's just as correct and much easier to read and understand.

Comment: I agree, but OP wanted a more formal answer.